# Can I use Excel INDIRECT function to run a formula contained as text in a reference cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a dynamic form that will return a date based on input in the format of "the Nth DayofWeek in Month, Year", for example, "the 3rd Monday in January 2018."

These are my lists:

```
+-----+--------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| Row | (A) Instance | (B) Instance Value | (C) DayofWeek | (D) DayofWeek Value | (E) Month | (F) Month Value |
+-----+--------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------------+
|   1 | 1st          |         0 | Monday        |     1,0,6,5,4,3,2 | January   |               1 |
|   2 | 2nd          |         7 | Tuesday       |     2,1,0,6,5,4,3 | February  |               2 |
|   3 | 3rd          |        14 | Wednesday     |     3,2,1,0,6,5,4 | March     |               3 |
|   4 | 4th          |        21 | Thursday      |     4,3,2,1,0,6,5 | April     |               4 |
|   5 | Last         |           | Friday        |     5,4,3,2,1,0,6 | May       |               5 |
|   6 |              |           | Saturday      |     6,5,4,3,2,1,0 | June      |               6 |
|   7 |              |           | Sunday        |     0,6,5,4,3,2,1 | July      |               7 |
|   8 |              |           |               |                   | August    |               8 |
|   9 |              |           |               |                   | September |               9 |
|  10 |              |           |               |                   | October   |              10 |
|  11 |              |           |               |                   | November  |              11 |
|  12 |              |           |               |                   | December  |              12 |
+-----+--------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

I use lookup formulas to get the values for whatever response is returned

```
+---------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----+--------------------------------+----+-------+
|         |             Instance             |             DayofWeek             | in |             Month              | of | Year  |
+---------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----+--------------------------------+----+-------+
| Name    | 3rd                              | Monday                            |    | January                        |    | 2018  |
| Value   | 14                               | 1,0,6,5,4,3,2                     |    | 1                              |    |       |
| Formula | =VLOOKUP(Instance,B2:C5,2,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP(DayofWeek,D2:E8,2,FALSE) |    | =VLOOKUP(Month,F2:G13,2,FALSE) |    | =year |
+---------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----+--------------------------------+----+-------+
```

Now I am trying to concatenate those values into a formula

> =CONCATENATE("=date(",year,",",Month,",1)+",Instance,"+choose(weekday(Date(",year,",",Month,",1),)),",DayofWeek,")")

Results in a cell containing this text, which looks like a formula, but doesn't run.

> =date(2018,1,1)+14+choose(weekday(Date(2018,1,1),)),1,0,6,5,4,3,2)

Is it possible to run this formula and return the value by calling it indirectly from another cell?

Other things I've tried:

I've done it this way because I've tried all other ways I can think of to copy the CHOOSE array into an indirect formula, and am foiled every time.

I can get this part to work:

```
=DATE(year,Month,1)+Instance
```

and this to display the array

`=INDIRECT("DayofWeek")`

`=N22&Chooseday solves as 43115+choose(weekday(Date(2018,1,1),)),1,0,6,5,4,3,2)`

`=DATE(year,Month,1)+occurrence+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(year,Month,1),1),INDIRECT("G19"))` returns #VALUE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need all that.  This formula will replace all the lookup tables:

```
=DATE(D1,MONTH(C1 & 1),1+A1*7) - WEEKDAY(DATE(D1,MONTH(C1 & 1),8-MATCH(B1,{"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},0)))
```

[image]